# Does partitioning of SSD affect on reliability and stability of work?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu. For making some speed upgrading I was looking for an SSD. HDD as I gathered from Google does not work the same as SSD in partitioning. To make a long story short, it does not create really partitions, but just conditional separates.

If I divide my SDD into partitions for two OSs will it in some way affect the reliability and stability of the OSs?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to say in the first paragraph. The answer to the second is easy: No, it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioning your hard drive is merely a logical division. It will not improve the performance of your system.

In fact I recommend to keep just one partition for simplicity. In this case you will use two operating system and I good way to do that is run one as a host and the other as a guest with some virtualization technique. I myself run Win 10 as host and start Ubuntu as guest operating system with Vagrant and VirtualBox.

Comment: It'll improve performance in case there are millions of files in the partition